# get the second div from an HTML content using regex JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I have a HTML code where i have the div with same id can we extract the second one.

HTML code

```
<div id="test>example </div>
<div id ="test">example11</div>
```

I need to extract the `example11`

This works `(?s)<div id="test>.*<div id ="test">(.*?)</div>` but i have a lot of div with same ID so this wont be good so can any one tell me do we have any other way to extract the content.

I know REGEX is not good for HTML paring and i have no choice.

Comment: it's a very bad idea to use the same id twice...

Comment: Why, did you say "I have no choice"? Regexp is a right choice for lexical layer not for grammar layer.

Comment: I know but the HTML content is not mine i just need to parse it.

Comment: @Aubin For HTML we have a lot of parsers like Jsoup,etc it will be very easy to parse but the thing is i can only parse using regex thats why i said i have no choice

Comment: don't parse HTML or XML with regex or [Cthulhu will claim your soul](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/342852). Use a parser like JSoup instead!

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
<div.*>.*</div><div.*>(.*)</div>
```

now you can select the first group. and its done ;)

a dirty solution would be

```
<div.*>.*</div><div.*>.*</div><div.*>.*</div><div.*>.*</div><div.*>.*</div><div.*>.*</div><div.*>.*</div><div.*>.*</div><div.*>.*</div><div.*>.*</div><div.*>(.*)</div>
```

hehe but aint so proud about this one ofc....uhm...will think about it..

Comment: Yes i can but if i have some 14 div with same id or class and i need to get the 13th div what should i do..Even this works fine<div id="test>.*<div id ="test">(.*?) which is already in the question.

Comment: How do you know you need the 13th and not the 11th? What's the discriminant?